# ExistsNode - What's wrong

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, xmltype

I create a table in oracle like this:

```
CREATE TABLE XML_TEMP (
          XML_DATA CLOB
);

INSERT INTO XML_TEMP(XML_DATA) VALUES('
    <envCFe versao="0.07" xmlns="http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat">
        <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
        <idLote>4095</idLote>
        <cUF>35</cUF>
        <LoteCFe>    
        </LoteCFe>
        <nSeg></nSeg>
        <dhEnvio>20171101101517</dhEnvio>
    </envCFe>
                                  ');
```

When I select the `existsNode` return 0

```
SELECT ExistsNode(XMLTYPE(XML_DATA), '/envCFe') HAS, XML_DATA FROM XML_TEMP;
```

I don't understang what's wrong, someone could help.

The link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c2b9e/5/0 has the SQLFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root node has a namespace, so you need to specify that using [the optional third argument](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions057.htm#SQLRF00637):

```
SELECT ExistsNode(XMLTYPE(XML_DATA), '/envCFe',
    'xmlns="http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat"') HAS, XML_DATA
FROM XML_TEMP;

       HAS XML_DATA                                                                        
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1                                                                                 
               <envCFe versao="0.07" xmlns="http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat">             
                   <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>                                                        
                   <idLote>4095</idLote>                                                   
                   <cUF>35</cUF>                                                           
                   <LoteCFe>                                                               
                   </LoteCFe>                                                              
                   <nSeg></nSeg>                                                           
                   <dhEnvio>20171101101517</dhEnvio>                                       
               </envCFe>
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c2b9e/12)

If you intend to use `ExistsNode` to filter your results, and since that function is deprecated, you could use [the `XMLExists` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions243.htm#SQLRF20013) for that scenario instead:

```
SELECT XML_DATA
FROM XML_TEMP
WHERE XMLExists(
  'declare namespace ns="http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat"; (: :)
  /ns:envCFe'
  PASSING XMLTYPE(XML_DATA)
);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c2b9e/13)

You can't get the result of that as part of a query result though, as your current query is doing.

Comment: Tks @alex-poole

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the namespace to existsNode function:

```
SELECT ExistsNode(XMLTYPE(XML_DATA), '/envCFe', 'xmlns="http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat"') HAS, XML_DATA FROM XML_TEMP;
```